# Simple Vimeo Regex: How to identify valid video urls but ignore user urls?

Tags: regex

This link is good:
`http://vimeo.com/22669590`

This link is bad:
`http://vimeo.com/gopro` or `http://vimeo.com/user1234`

Here's my current Regex: `/vimeo\.com\/([^&]*)/i`

How can I catch the good (which this regex does) but avoid the bad (which this regex does not)?

Comment: Think about the problem. "Valid" URLs only contain numbers after the domain name, so you'll need a regex that only allows this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears videos only have numeric value. Why not just match where entire string is numeric after the vimeo.com/

```
/vimeo\.com\/\d+$
```